# Too many open Files Error in Kafka, when running daemon using non-root user

Tags: apache-kafka

When I run kafka as a service on my linux machine with a lot of topics and partitions I run into error "Too many open files". I have set the ending of the file `/etc/security/limits.conf` like this

```
*         hard    nofile      500000
*         soft    nofile      500000
kafka     hard    nofile      500000
kafka     soft    nofile      500000
root      hard    nofile      500000
root      soft    nofile      500000
```

But whatever I do, when running as root, no problems arise. When running as kafka user, Too Many Open files error arises after about 10 minutes. What can I do to fix this, I would rather not run Kafka as root.

Comment: What are your topic and partition counts?

Comment: What do you mean by lot of topic and partitions, can you tell me the count.

Comment: "find | wc -l" gives me 15000 items in the data directory. But starting as a deamon under kafka user gives the error, I am running a nohup as root right now, working a full day now, without issues ...

Comment: ulimit -a | grep "open files" -> 500000

Comment: "cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr" -> 12832   0       810108